# Texture is black and won’t change

Tags: workflow, texture-painting

[image]

I’ve been watching “Blender Guru” make a donut and following. I first made my texture paint fine, but when I did the displacement something went wrong. I don’t remember why, it just turned black.

I went to redo my texture paint and now it’s just black. No matter what I do, my paint won’t show and it is only black.

Also, this might help more. I did change the blend in texture painting and I could paint on it. But it was the cloud texture. I tried to change it, but now I can’t paint anything on it.

Comment: Do you have a light in the scene?

Comment: I do have a light

Comment: Share some screenshots of your setting or even share your Blend File

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, but I fixed it by following the instructions to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75662/texture-paints-brush-is-always-black?rq=1). Here are the steps:

**1.** In the Texture Paint tab, press **N**, and click **Tool** on the right side-bar.

**2.** Under **Brushes** click the **X** button to delete the brush, then add a new brush.

**3.** Then select a colour under **Brush Settings**, go to the **Colour Picker** dropdown, and then draw over the object.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I did this by starting over from a few steps back. There was a mask texture on it, and I deleted it. Then it worked